# Display css sub-menus if active

Tags: css

Can someone please help me to display active menus - ex. when I select the top menu og one of the submenus (how has sub-menues), I would like to view the other menu items when selected.

See example at the link below.

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/PhuBQ/20/)

Comment: A little more explanation ...
 The submenus for selected top menu to be displayed
 or if you have selected one of the submenus, then the sub-menus in the same groups is shown.

 Hope you understand

Comment: Do you want the submenus displayed on hover or on click?

Comment: Hey Ana, both on click and hover - like this example http://jsfiddle.net/PhuBQ/20/ - but the selected menu og sub-menu should always be visible. - im not shoure this problem can be fixed whith css only..

Answer (score 0):

If you want them displayed on click, then check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/S8Kwq/

In this case, you have to target them using `a:focus + ul, a:active + ul`

If you want them displayed on mouseover, then you target them using `a:hover + ul`